# When using Android Studio's support annotations, should I also provide checks in code?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I used to have this code:

```
public final static class GoogleMapsZoomLevel {

    public static final int MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL = 0;
    public static final int MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 21;

    private int zoomLevel;

    private static final String ERROR_ZOOM_LEVEL_OUT_OF_BOUNDS = "Zoom level should be within " + MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL + " and " + MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL;

    private GoogleMapsZoomLevel() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public GoogleMapsZoomLevel(int zoomLevel) {
        if (zoomLevel < MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL || zoomLevel > MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ERROR_ZOOM_LEVEL_OUT_OF_BOUNDS);
        }
        this.zoomLevel = zoomLevel;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(zoomLevel);
    }
}
```

Today I read an [article](https://medium.com/sebs-top-tips/annotations-to-support-your-contracts-609ff259d5df) on Android Studio Support Annotations, and I changed my code to this:

```
public final static class GoogleMapsZoomLevel {

    public static final int MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL = 0;
    public static final int MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 21;

    private int zoomLevel;

    private static final String ERROR_ZOOM_LEVEL_OUT_OF_BOUNDS = "Zoom level should be within " + MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL + " and " + MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL;

    private GoogleMapsZoomLevel() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public GoogleMapsZoomLevel(@IntRange(from=MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL, to=MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL) int zoomLevel) {
        if (zoomLevel < MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL || zoomLevel > MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ERROR_ZOOM_LEVEL_OUT_OF_BOUNDS);
        }
        this.zoomLevel = zoomLevel;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(zoomLevel);
    }
}
```

For more clarity, the change is the following line:

```
public GoogleMapsZoomLevel(int zoomLevel) {
```

was turned into this:

```
public GoogleMapsZoomLevel(@IntRange(from=MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL, to=MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL) int zoomLevel) {
```

Now, right below that line, I am doing some safety checks in both versions of the code:

```
if (zoomLevel < MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL || zoomLevel > MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ERROR_ZOOM_LEVEL_OUT_OF_BOUNDS);
        }
```

Question is, now that I use the support annotations do I keep these checks or not? My reasoning behind keeping the checks is that those annotations are only a temporary phenomena in this particular IDE and in the event of working on this code in another IDE, they will become unusable. Also, they are easily recognizable and explicitly speak to all kinds of Java developers with all backgrounds, unlike the Android Studio-specific annotations.

Technically, these checks are unreachable in the moment, because the IDE doesnt allow me to use that constructor, but now thinking about it, if I use some code to pass values to the constructor, instead of invoking it with hardcoded values, those I have no power over, and might be wrong, so these checks are actually reachable, right?

Am I right, or should I remove the checks below the annotated code?